# How to perform Menu key click in background service?

Tags: android, shell, click, android-service

I'm making an app that triggers a click on the Menu key when a shake movement occurs.
I've tried this to perform the click :

```
try
{
    java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 82");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: get a weak reference to the activity object and invoke the click function on it

Comment: Thank you, can you explain that a little more please

Comment: Doubt, your app has a privilege to invoke `input` command.

Comment: @Onik which privileges are you talking about?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `e.getMessage()` gives you `permission denied`. You cannot execute most of the shell command from an app (on stock `Android`).

Comment: If you were able to programatically press random keys on the phone while other apps were in the foreground, this would be a huge security hole. Forget it, not possible.

Comment: You are absolutely right.